# TypeError: setup_module() got an unexpected keyword argument 'data'

Tags: python

May I please get assistance on this error as I've been trying but it returns a TypeError.

```
bank = setup_module(data = data, target = 'Creditability', 
                  normalize = True, stage=None,
                  transformation = True,
               train_size = 0.8, # training over 80% of available data
                  handle_unknown_categorical = True, 
                  unknown_categorical_method = 'most_frequent',
                  remove_multicollinearity = True, #rop one of the two features that are highly correlated with each other
                  ignore_low_variance = True,#all categorical features with statistically insignificant variances are removed from the dataset.
                  combine_rare_levels = True,# all levels in categorical features below the threshold defined in rare_level_threshold param are combined together as a single level
                  numeric_imputation='median',
                  categorical_imputation='mode',
            ordinal_features = {'Account_Balance':['No Account','None','Below 200 DM','200 DM or Above'],
                               'Value_Savings_Stocks':['None','Below 100 DM','[100, 500)','[500, 1000)','Above 1000'],
                               'Length_of_current_employment':['Unemployed','<1 Year','[1, 4)','[4, 7)','Above 7'],
                               'Instalment_per_cent':['Below 20%','[20%, 25%)','(25%, 35%)','Above 35%'],
                               'Occupation':['Unemployed, unskilled','Unskilled Permanent Resident','Skilled','Executive'],
                                'No_of_Credits_at_this_Bank':['1','2 or 3','4 or 5','Above 6'],
                                'No_of_dependents':['Less than 3','3 or More']
                               },
            fix_imbalance = True,
            numeric_features=num_col,
             session_id=1,)
```

Comment: please use hashtags for the technologies and the tools that you are using, so that you'll find help soon. Now, nobody knows what library or project you are targeting at. Best of luck!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The best route would be to look into the function "setup_module" and find out what the keyword argument for data is. For example, it might be "dataset=".

You can find this out by holding ctrl and clicking the function name to go directly to it's source code.

It is not recommended but you could also just remove the "data=" if you are confident that data is the first argument that the function requires.